# Can not ping interface's public address of my instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ping, amazon-vpc

I have basically 2 *VPCs* where `CSR 1000v` is deployed in each *VPC* (**CSR1** and **CSR2**). I attach a drawing my setup below.

[image]

I created 2 *interfaces* in deferent subnets within its *VPC CIDR* in each VM and attached with an **Elastic IPs**. My problem is, that from **CSR1**, I cannot ping the interface *`Gi2`* and *`Gi3`* of **CSR2**, as well as from **CSR2** to Gi2 and *Gi3* of **CSR1**. However, pinging Primary network interface *`Gi1`* is always successful.

For *Security Groups*, I'm allowing *all traffic* inbound and outbound, and I added another rule for *all ICPM IPv4 traffic* as well as well as CLI of each VPC.

I checked the logs on `Gi3` interface of **CSR2** after ping from **CSR1** and here what I have got:
`096280364590 eni-0689ce924ea36ad58 35.166.239.202 172.1.1.46 0 0 1 10 1000 1544798122 1544798178 ACCEPT OK`

It looks like 10 packets were sent and it was accepted traffic. However, the ping was not successful.

However, using *VPC peering*, I could ping the private interfaces of the other *VPC* but its Elastic IPs not.

How can solve this? I need it for the configuration of `GRE tunnel` since Routing protocols are supported over a tunnel only on `CSR 1000v` in AWS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re overcomplicating it again.

1. Have Elastic IP *only* on Gi1 on each CSR.
2. Gi2 and Gi3 shouldn’t have EIP, only the VPC IP.
3. Create a GRE tunnel between the two Gi1 interface addresses.
4. Run your OSPF over that tunnel to propagate the respective Gi2 and Gi3 prefixes to the other CSR.

Those Gi2 and Gi3 on each CSR are your internal interfaces. They shouldn’t have public IP and should only be reachable from the other side over the tunnel. Once the tunnel is working and OSPF running.

For now forget Gi2 and Gi3 and make sure you’ve got a working GRE tunnel between the Gi1 interfaces.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: thanks for the answer. In fact, I want the tunnel in  _Gi2_ and _Gi3_ because I will have more than one router in different **VPCs**  and what I would like to achieve is that I will be able to measure the loads on those interfaces, each interface will be having its own load measurement. If I use only _Gi1_ and I have 2 different **CSR** which are attached to **CSR 1**, that link with that interface might get overloaded.

Comment: @KhalilMebarkia Make a simple tunnel work first. Until you have GRE + OSPF working between TWO routers don’t worry about more complex setups. Really.

Comment: it is working! thanks a lot :) Just one issue. Why `show ospf neighbor` does not show anything?